# Django: Can't install external middleware

Tags: django, middleware

So far I've only ever had to enable django middleware that appears to already be installed on my system. This was done by adding the relevant line to my settings.py file.

Now, however, I'm trying to install 3rd party middleware, and having all kinds of trouble.

The package is django-mobi, and in following the instructions https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mobi/> I just keep getting an Error 200 in my browser when I run the apache restart script after altering the settings.py file.

Here's what I've done:

1) Placed the "package" in my project path, which googling suggests means anything below "myproject" directory:

```
$ ls
django-mobi-0.1.7  django-mobi-0.1.7.tar.gz  manage.py  mobi  myproject
```

2) Added the line specified to the settings.py file

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'mobi.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
)
```

Restarting apache without that last mobi line commented out of the tuple results in an Error 200, even though I've got debug mode on, so it's of no help in diagnosing the problem.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Some of the middleware has an order, meaning it needs to be before or after some other middleware, is there any requirement like that in the installation process

Comment: Did you setup the MOBI_REDIRECT_URL variable on the `settings.py` file

Comment: Hi Leonardo, shouldn't be any dependency, as I've put the 3rd party code at the very bottom. I did not set up a MOBI_REDIRECT_URL no, as I haven't seen any instruction about it

Comment: I found the problem. Upon unpacking, there's an extra .py file called middleware in which the function MobileDetectionMiddleware resides. So my setting.py file middleware_classes tuple had to contain 'mobi.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware' and now it works! Thanks for ur time

Comment: It would be a good idea that you answer your question for any future reference or if someone else needs help in something similar.

Comment: ok thanks, just did. I couldn't before because I can't answer a Q within 8 hours of posting it (stack overflow for new users I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it. Based on the directory structure of what I untarred, there's an extra 'middleware' filename that needed to be added to the path in settings.py. So now it looks like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'mobi.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
    )
```

And it works fine

Comment: The `.middleware` bit has been added to the [django-mobi README](https://bitbucket.org/kencochrane/django-mobi).